# custom css style not work in React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs

```
<Button type="submit" className="Form__Button mr-20">Sign In</Button>
```

I'm working on jsx file, I want to add custom style for above Button if I try this

```
{<style type="text/css">
  {`
   .Form__Button {
      background-color: #52C4B9;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 25px;
    }
  `}
</style>
```

But if I use style in a different css file it not work

Comment: You can put this style in another css file and import it or you can use inline style

Comment: That what I have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**:

Create a new file called "App.css" and insert some CSS code in it:

```
.Form__Button {
   background-color: #52C4B9;
   color: white;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   border-radius: 25px;
}
```

In your JSX file:

```
import './App.css';
```

Option 2:

```
class MyHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const myButton = {
      background-color: #52C4B9;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 25px;
    };
    return (
      <div>
      <Button type="submit" style={myButton}>Sign In</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```